# How to place image on right corner of pdf using node js?

Tags: node.js

I have one pdf file and one image file which is the signature of the client. I need to place the client signature image on the top right corner of every page of pdf. This whole process is in node js so I have used the pdf-lib npm package to attach image on pdf. The current issue I'm unable to place the image on the top-right corner.

Below is the logic which I used to set an image on the top-right corner of the pdf but this logic is not true for every case in some cases when the width of the image or pdf changes then it's not worked as expected. Sometimes images are getting too much small or sometimes too much large.Just because I set fix height and width. As I don't know how to calculate it dynamically

[image]

```
        const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
        for (let i = 0; i < pdfDoc.getPageCount(); i++) {
            let imagePage='';
            imagePage = pdfDoc.getPage(i);
            console.log(i+1)
            console.log(imagePage.getWidth())
            let xx=imagePage.getWidth()
            console.log(imagePage.getHeight())
            console.log(img.width)
            console.log(img.height)
            let yy=imagePage.getHeight()
            imagePage.drawImage(img, {
                x: xx-150,
                y: yy-70,
                width: 70,
                height: 70
            })
        }
```

[image]

Please check console values below

```
595.5 ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​imagePage.getWidth()​​​ 

842.2499787 ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​imagePage.getHeight()​​​

1200 ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​img.width​​​

700 ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​img.height
```

please check the above image where I attached the signature to pdf but in this case, the signature image is not properly visible so how can I set the image to pdf on the top-right corner?
How can I calculate the x and y position dynamically for any pdf?

Comment: Please [edit] the question, and add the output from the `Console.log...` lines for creating the image that you attached to this question.

Comment: Added a screenshot of console values @Luuk

Comment: that's a screenshot of the code, and I did mean what is the output from the `Console.log` statements?   (And please post that as TEXT, see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) )

Comment: @Luuk I have added text values of console.log().

Comment: the height/width ration of you image is 700/1200 = 0.58.  But the created image in your PDF has ration 700/700 = 1. This is leading to a stretchend image, because target is less high than the original.

Comment: @Luuk Image height is 700 but i defined Height is "70" not 700 please have a look again

Comment: It does not matter if I type 700x700 or 70x70, it evaluates to the SAME problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to get dynamic x and y values to set an image on the top-right corner of the pdf

```
let xx=imagePage.getWidth();
console.log(imagePage.getHeight());
console.log("[PAGE_HEIGHT]",imagePage.getHeight());
const imgHeight = img.height;
const imgWidth = img.width;
console.log("[SIGNATURE_IMAGE_WIDTH]",img.width);
console.log("[SIGNATURE_IMAGE_HEIGHT]",img.height);
const marginX = 50;
let yy=imagePage.getHeight();
imagePage.drawImage(img, {
    x: xx -marginX-imgWidth,
    y: yy- marginX-imgHeight,
    width: imgWidth,
    height: imgHeight
})
```

margin is a fixed value to move an image from the top and right sides to get a proper view.
I have removed image height and width from the actual page width and height that will return top right corner.

Comment: How would you position it to the left? I don't understand these x and y values..